# CodeIgniter - Not working to pass array to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't understand why this is not putting the database values on the page. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong with this code? I'm a novice at CodeIgniter and this is the first time I'm trying to pass an array from model to controller to view.

Controller Code:

```
public function showuser(){
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $data['user']= $this->user_model->view_user($id);       
        $this->load->view('include/header');
        $this->load->view('user_view',$data); 
        $this->load->view('include/footer');
}
```

Model Code:

```
public function view_user($id){
        $this->db->where('userid', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query->result();
}
```

View Code:

```
<table width="300" border="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td width="143">First Name</td>
    <td width="143"><?php echo $data['user']->firstname; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td><?php echo $data->lastname; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Company</td>
    <td><?php echo $data->company; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><?php echo $data->email; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Phone</td>
    <td><?php echo $data->phone; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Fax</p></td>
    <td><?php echo $data->fax; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Address 1</td>
    <td><?php echo $data->address1; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Address 2</p></td>
    <td><?php echo $data->address2; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Address 3</td>
    <td><?php echo $data->address3; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>City</td>
    <td><?php echo $data->city; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>State/Region/Province</td>
    <td><?php echo $data->state; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Postal Code</td>
    <td><?php echo $data->zipcode; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td><?php echo $data->username; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Account Type</td>
    <td><?php echo $data->usertype; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use variable `$data` inside your view. Just directly print variables by `$data` array keys, for example, `$user->firstname` etc.
More about views: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Also, I think you should have to return `$query->row()`, not `$query->result()` inside your model, because it is getting data just about one user.

Answer (score 0):

Another way  is
use **foreach($user as $u)** and print like **$u['firstname']** etc in **php tag.**